# Split a NSString to multiple commandline arguments

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am getting a commandline string in my application and I am trying to run the same as an NSTask. I can convert it as a C-String and run it using system.

```
system([commandlineStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

But I prefer using NSTask instead. For running as NSTask, I need to split the string as command and an array of arguments. Splitting with *space* doesn't work since there could be arguments with space in between. Currently they are either escaped or quoted. For eg:

```
cp "~/File with spaces" ~/Folder\ with\ spaces
```

Is there a built in way to split the string to multiple arguments or write a custom parsing logic for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The format you are trying to parse is the shell command line, there is a program which is rather good at that - the shell. If you did choose to parse it yourself your job would not be finished - you would still have to locate the program to run. The shell does that by taking the command name, `cp` in your example, and searching for a matching program using a set of paths. To copy this you would have to perform the same search.

There is a much easier way, the shell it itself a program you can invoke with `NSTask`, and the shell had an option, `-c`, which takes a single string as argument and parses and execute that string value as a command line. So you can use `NSTask`, pass the first argument as `@"-c"`, and the second as the string you have. This will handle everything for you - spaces, escapes, pipes, redirection, *et al*.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am quite new to OSX and I will not have much control on the end machines where the program is going to run. Which is a shell (sh, bash) that I can safely assume to be present on every OSX machine? Can you point me to any documentation is available?

Comment: If the command line you are being passed uses peculiar features of a particular shell you will need to invoke that one, but it sounds like it only uses core shell features which are common across shells, so just use `/bin/sh` – this is a version of bash on recent macOS versions. Documentation is in the usual place for *nix, type `man sh`. If this fails you might need to install the Xcode Command Line Tools package to get the *nix man pages. Xcode used to have the man pages as part of its docs, but in one of the many negative improvements to Xcode/Apple help they were removed. HTH